# Real Analysis Question concerning existence of curve and derivative?

Tags: real-analysis

So I'm doing some self study on Real Analysis from a friend's set of notes and classwork from last semester.  I'm trying to prepare myself for next year.  Anyway, I got caught up in the following question and was looking for some direction.  With out explicitly knowing what $f(x)$ is how do I go about showing that $f(0)$, $f'(0)$ exist?  Do I have to choose a function?

Suppose that $f \colon R \to R$ is differentiable everywhere, and that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = L$$
for some real number $L$.

1. Find $f(0)$. Prove your answer.
2. item Find $f'(0)$. Prove your answer.
3. Give an example of a function $f$ satisfying the above conditions such that $f''(0)$ does not exist. Prove your answer.

Comment: Suppose $f(0) \ne 0$. Use continuity of $f$ to obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The claim that $f$ is everywhere differentiable actually tells you everything you need: it tells you that $f$ exists everywhere (since the definition of the derivative doesn't work if the function doesn't exist),it tells you that $f'$ exists everywhere, and it tells you that $f$ is continuous everywhere (since differentiability implies continuity).

To address the questions asked:

1. We know that $x^2\to0$ as $x\to0$. As such, $f(x)$ can only have one limit as $x\to0$ to prevent the $\frac{1}{x^2}$ from blowing the whole thing up to infinity.  What is that limit?  Then, use continuity to deduce $f(0)$ from the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to0$.
2. Remember that
   $$
   f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}.
   $$
   You know $f(0)$ from $1$; plug this in to get a limit expression for $f'(0)$. This statement will be related to the limit given in the assumptions, but not equal to it; try to think about what the limit must be to make the limit in the assumptions possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For the example, try $f(x)=x^3 \sin(1/x)$ when $x\ne 0$, and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: So for this example, I think that the first derivative is not continuous at 0... but how do I go about proving this?

Comment: The first derivative at $0$ is $0$. If $x\ne 0$, then $f'(x)=-x\cos(1/x)+3x^2\sin(1/x)$. This has limit $0$ as $x\to 0$, so $f'(x)$ is continuous at $0$. But $\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0}=-\cos(1/x)+3x\sin(1/x)$ (if $x\ne 0$). This does not have a limit as $x\to 0$, since $\cos(1/x)$ wiggles crazily.